# Angular use enums from typescript npm package, undefined error

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have an angular application which uses enums from an typescript package.

So my setup is basically this:

**Angular**

```
import { TestEnum } from 'my-enum-package';

Component {
    enumVal = TestEnum; // Make the enum available in the component template.

    constructor() {
         if(exampleVar === TestEnum.Value1) { /* Do stuff */ }
    }
}
```

**My enum package (typescript)**

```
export enum TestEnum {
  Unknown = 0,
  Value1 = 1,
  Value2 = 2
}
```

index.ts from package

```
export * from './testenum.ts'
```

This works fine in development mode (ng serve). But when I use this in production mode I get an error when opening the component.

*Cannot read property 'Value1' of undefined*

Somehow the enum is available in angular but not the values, and this only happens in production mode. I read somewhere that the export enum should be const, but if this gives me a lot of warnings troughout my code.

errors like this:

*'const' enums can only be used in property or index access expressions or the right hand side of an import declaration or export assignment or type query.*

What is a possible solution for this? 
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** The goal here is to share some enums between multiple angular applications, if there is a smarter way to do this then using ts npm package, please let me know.

Comment: Can your try to export like this export {TestEnum } from './testenum.ts', I think this was recently reported to compiler issue

Comment: @Indraraj26 same result unfortunately: Cannot read property 'Value1' of undefined

Comment: For future readers, this might helps understand why const enums should not be used to solve this problem: https://ncjamieson.com/dont-export-const-enums/